# Unit Testing Stops In Middle When I use Console.Readline()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want to mock `Console.ReadLine()` using MOQ but I do not know how to do that. I tried to search on the internet but I couldn't find an appropriate answer.
I have tried various things but none had worked so far. This is just a demo file. I am working on a console app where I have to use `Console.ReadLine()`. But I do not know how to mock the function that is using `Console.ReadLine()`.

```
using System;

namespace _Calci
{
    public class Operands
    {
        public int num1;
        public int num2;
    }

    public class ret
    {
        public virtual int _ret()
        { 
            return (Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
    }

    public class Calci : ret
    {
        ret retObj = new ret();

        public int Multiply()
        {
            int result;
            int num1 = 4;
            result = retObj._ret() * num1;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Unit Testing File:

```
using Xunit;
using _Calci;
using Moq;

namespace Testings
{
    public class Testing
    {
        [Fact]
        public void MultiplyTesting()
        {
            Mock<ret> mockingVar = new Mock<ret>();
            mockingVar.Setup(x=> x._ret()).Returns(()=>5);
            Calci calciObj = new Calci();
            int expected = 20;
            int actual = calciObj.Multiply();
        
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Calci` class inject through constructor `ret` object instead of making a new instance inside the `Calci`. Then in your test you'll be able to inject mocked `ret` that returns any int like this: `Calci calciObj = new Calci(mockingVar.Object);`

Comment: I have done the things that you have said. But  how can I get the actual value in Unit Testing file

Comment: @Nik By calling `Multiply();` you'll receive actual value. The point of your test is asserting whether the number from `ret` is multiplied by 4 or not. You're mocking the input for wchich you know the output so you can assert it.

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble understanding it. I have made a constructor. But how can I call _ret method inside Multiply() function without instantiating ret class

Comment: public class Calci : ret{
        //ret retObj = new ret();
        
        public Calci(ret obj){  }
        public int Multiply(){

            int result;           
            
            int num1 = 4;
            
            result = _ret() * num1;
            return result;
        }
    }

Comment: Hey Thank You, bro, I have figured out how to do it because of you.

Comment: @Nik I'm glad! Could you mark the answer as accepted, since the issue is resolved?